# Is it possible to pull data off of old Windows XP RAID 0 striped disks that are no longer in a RAID setup?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, ntfs

I have two hard drives that used to be in a RAID 0 setup on an unknown computer with unknown RAID hardware. There’s no way for me to get any more info than that.

On Bodhi Linux using a Hex editor I can verify that data is still on these two drives, it’s just striped and thus useless in its current form.

How can I go about merging the data together to recover it? The file system was NTFS, operating system Windows XP, and I have a copy of the partition table which was on drive 0. I’m also using the `dd` command to make a full copy of both drives just in case.

Comment: You don't, you would need to have the ability to present an identical RAID array in order to pull the information off the drives you don't even know what RAID mode (0.1,10,5,6,50,60) was used

Comment: How much do you know about the original RAID setup?  Is it RAID 1 (mirroring) or another kind of RAID (striping)?  Also, if they show up as unpartitioned blank drives, why do you think you might be able to get data from them?  Is it possible they were wiped before you got them?

Comment: I didn't think we were supposed to give answers in comments.

Comment: I only know there's two identical drives. They were in a computer hard drive caddy capable of only holding two drives. Screws were holding them in only on one side, making me think it was in some sort of older desktop. That's all I know.  I also know it's not impossible like @Ramhound is suggesting. It's just not as easy as some would like.

Comment: @herculeesjr never said it wasn't possible, I said, given the information you provided we can't tell you how.

Comment: As @Ramhound already mentioned, it is going to be impossible to get this answered on the format of this site. For starters, if you try out any solution we give you and the solution itself is incorrect (very probable) you will definitely destroy any chance to find out what data is on the drive, because the partition table on the drive itself is altered/recreated if not perfectly correct.

Comment: @herculeesjr If you do that question will just be closed as a duplicate.  Question has pending reopen votes.  Don't submit this question again, this question likely will be reopened, if you submit it again a moderator will be notified

Comment: Earn more reputation by not submitting the same question again and continue when/where appropriate improve your existing questions and by answering questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery" at http://www.freeraidrecovery.com/ is able to retrieve lost RAID info and recover data from the drives.
After installing the program and opening it you can either select your hard drives or drive image files. Even raw drive images made with the `dd` command.
After selecting the drives click what type of RAID they used to be and it will start analyzing them. For me with the two drives (80GB each, RAID 0, so 160GB) imaged onto my SATA SSD it took 5-10minutes. Once either the Scan Progress bar or Confidence bar reaches 100% it will finish and give you options on what to do.
For the easiest method to recover all data select "Create The Array Image File" and select where you want it to save a VHD copy of the RAID array. Once it is finished you can mount the VHD file using Disk Management in Windows and browse it like a normal hard drive.

Comment: I was extremely skeptical to this software, since it has very little info about it online. However, I installed it and it worked just as you said. I got my old Raid0 from an old WinXP machine back and created a VHD from it. My antivirus software has not kicked in as yet, so things are looking good :)